# JQuery Disabled dropdown options based on selection from another

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I've got two dropdown lists. Each contains the same list of times. When a time in list "A" is selected I want to disabled the same and all prior times in list "B".

```
List A                   List B
------                   ------
06:00 AM                 06:00 AM
07:00 AM                 07:00 AM
08:00 AM                 08:00 AM
...                      ...
```

So when someone clicks on say 07:00 AM in list "A", that time and prior in list "B" would be disabled.

```
$('#listA').on('change', function(){
   ...
});
```

+1 for economical coding.

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing this which catches it both ways:

```
function setDisableOptions( from, to ) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'change', '[name="' + from + '"]', function () {
        var s = $( this ).prop( 'selectedIndex' ) + 1;
        var l = $( '[name="' + from + '"] option' ).length;
        $( this ).find( 'option' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
        for ( var i = 0; i <= l; i++ ) {
            if ( i <= s ) {
                $( '[name="' + to + '"] > option:nth-child(' + i + ')' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            } else {
                $( '[name="' + to + '"] > option:nth-child(' + i + ')' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            }
        }
    } );
    $( document.body ).on( 'change', '[name="' + to + '"]', function () {
        var s = $( this ).prop( 'selectedIndex' ) + 1;
        var l = $( '[name="' + to + '"] option' ).length;
        $( this ).find( 'option' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
        for ( var i = 0; i <= l; i++ ) {
            if ( i >= s ) {
                $( '[name="' + from + '"] > option:nth-child(' + i + ')' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            } else {
                $( '[name="' + from + '"] > option:nth-child(' + i + ')' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            }
        }
    } );
};
```

which is called like:

```
setDisableOptions( 'fromInputName', 'toInputName');
```

Comment: I need the correct index value returned in the e.sibling reference. I don't think this.index() works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better and elegant way of doing this (edit from your code)

```js
$('select').change(function () {
    var s = $(this).prop('selectedIndex')+1;
    var selected = $(this);
    var fcontrol = function () {
        if (selected.attr('id') == 'listA') {
         return $(this).index()+1 < s;
        } else {
         return $(this).index()+1 > s;
        };
    }
    var others = $(this).siblings('select').children() 
    others.prop('disabled', false).filter(fcontrol).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="listA" size="5">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
</select>
<select id="listB" size="5">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```js
$('#listA').on('change', function(){
 var s = $(this).prop('selectedIndex')+1;
 var l = $("#listA option").length;
 for(var i = 0; i <= l; i++){
  if(i <= s) {
   $("#listB > option:nth-child(" + i + ")").attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
   $("#listB > option:nth-child(" + i + ")").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="listA" name="sometext" size="5">
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>
  <option>text3</option>
  <option>text4</option>
  <option>text5</option>
</select>
<select id="listB" name="sometext" size="5">
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>
  <option>text3</option>
  <option>text4</option>
  <option>text5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: One more kink. If an item in "B" is clicked it should also disable the items in "A" above that time. This example http://jsfiddle.net/4Z74U/14/ works but on old javascript libraries.

Comment: I'm trying to rework the code which may work just need to check the index values instead of the actual values: